# Having trouble while dragging and then drop of table row in table layout in Androidstudio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing problem while drag and dropping of table row into table layout.
Below is the code.
The code before adding table row

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

While dropping the table row it shows like below

[image]

After adding table row the code and snapshot is below

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="4"></TableRow>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `TableLayout`, don't put a `TableRow` inside from the design tools, but directly put your widget (like `TextView`, `Button`, etc) and the design tool will build the view for you ;)

Comment: yes I observed that, but in many tutorials they are also putting Tablerow and why it is causing problem and adding more tablerows??

Comment: Maybe the tool got a evolution. Android studio is always changing and tutorials get old and deprecated really quickly.